# Is there a way to get list of preinstalled apps in android?

Tags: android, python

For testing purposes I want to get a list of pre-installed or system apps in an android device, so I could select and lunch one.
I am working with ADB and and Appium python client, is there any way to achieve that with either one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
adb shell pm list packages -s
```

which is returning the list of system packages